# Coordinates of a symmetrical figures in a coordinate system

Tags: geometry, coordinate-systems

Let's say that I have a triangle with vertexes *(0, 0), (0.5, 1), (1, 0)*. I need to find a coordinates of a point symmetrical or a line symmetrical triangle. But how do I calculate that without drawing? For example, the line is *y=1.5* or a point is (0.5, 1.5). I know that coordinates of a new triangle should be *(0, 3), (0.5, 2), (1, 3)*, but are there any formulas to find it? I know $\frac {y - v}{x - u}\times a$ and $x^2 + (y - b)^2 = u^2 + (v - b)^2$ but they didn't work for me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: One usually translates the line to be the $y=0$ axis because there is easy to see how to reflect it(just negate the $y$ component). Now sure how to do it with a point. What do you mean by that?

Comment: If your given triangle has vertices $A,B,C$ and you want the triangle symmetrical with respect to a given point $P$, all you do is let $A'$ be the point as far from $P$ as $A$ is, on the line through $P$ and $A$, but on the opposite side of $P$ from $A$; similarly for $B'$ and $C'$, and those three points are the ones you want. If you need a formula, $A'=P+(P-A)=2P-A$, similarly for $B',C'$.

Comment: @gerry-myerson Thank you very much, this is exactly what I was looking for!